# Parsing Rails JSON associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails API that exports JSON similar to

```
# /customers/1.json
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Some name","address":"Street 12-3",
  "county":{"id":2,"name":"MyCounty"},
  "contracts":[
    {"id":2663,"number":"6-2/7 (2011)", "county":{"id":2,"name":"MyCounty"}},
}
```

The client Rails (**3.2.2**) has Resource models: `Customer`, `Contract` and `County` all connected to that API. When I fetch `Customer.find(1)`, it seems to parse the associated objects into two different Classes based on whether the original class was already loaded.

Consider:

```
rails console
c = Customer.find 1
#<Customer:0x0... @attributes={"id"=>1, "county"=>#<County:0x0...>,
"contracts"=>[#<Customer::Contract:0x0...> ....
```

**Note:** the association class names: `County` and `Customer::Contract`

Now if I reload the console, it becomes:

```
reload!
c = Customer.find 1
#<Customer:0x0... @attributes={"id"=>1, "county"=>#<Customer::County:0x0...>,
"contracts"=>[#<Customer::Contract:0x0...> ....
```

But if I start new console and before anything make Rails load the classes, it becomes:

```
rails console
County.new
Contract.new
c = Customer.find 1
#<Customer:0x0... @attributes={"id"=>1, "county"=>#<Customer::County:0x0...>,
"contracts"=>[#<Contract:0x0...> ....
```

Is there any way to let Rails *always* parse these the same way?

**EDIT:** code examples:

```
# app/models/contract.rb
class Contract < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = APP_CONFIG['k2api']
  self.format = :json
end

# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = APP_CONFIG['k2api']
  self.format = :json
  # accessor to ActiveResource response headers
  add_response_method :http_response
end

# app/models/county.rb
class County < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = APP_CONFIG['k2api']
  self.format = :json
end
```

Comment: I would bet this has something to do with how your models are defined. Is your `Contract` model namespaced in a folder or is it subclassed to Customer? Posting the code of the models and their directory structure might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through [Rails ActiveResource source](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/master/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L1478), the answer is as I began to suspect - Rails checks if a class with the name of the association is already defined or creates a simple `ActiveResource::Base` subclass itself.

To make my app behave consistently regardless of whether any models have been loaded or not, I force-load all my recource-models in initializer:

```
[Customer, Contract, County].map &:new
```

BTW, for some reason the eager loading mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027312/rails-3-loading-all-models-on-startup)) gave me problems with Factory Girl.